# Unable to apply styles to a specific text of a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I would like to know if there is a way to apply styles to a specific text inside the prop.testimonios because that data is inside an object. In itself, what I should achieve would be to apply bold to: "**freeCodeCamp cambió mi vida**" of the first component, "**freeCodeCamp fue la puerta de entrada a mi carrera**" of the second component and "**freeCodeCamp me dio las habilidades**" of the third component. What occurs to me is to make a filter with a replace, 'but I don't know if it would be the appropriate way to apply it or is there a simpler way?

Thank you very much!

Testimonio.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../hojas-de-estilo/Testimonio.css'

function Testimonio(props) {

  return (
    <div className='contenedor-testimonio'>
      <img 
          className='imagen-testimonio' 
          src={require(`../imagenes/testimonio-${props.imagen}.png`)} 
          alt={`Foto de ${props.imagen}`} />
      <div className='contenedor-texto-testimonio'>
        <p className='nombre-testimonio'>
          <strong>{props.nombre}</strong> en {props.pais}
        </p>
        <p className='cargo-testimonio'>
          {props.cargo} en <strong>{props.empresa}</strong>
        </p>
        <p className='texto-testimonio'>"{props.testimonio}."</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Testimonio;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Testimonio from './componentes/Testimonio';

function App() {

  const users = [
    {
      nombre:'Shawn Wang',
      pais:'Singapur',
      imagen:'Shawn',
      cargo:'Ingeniero de software',
      empresa:'Amazon',
      testimonio:'Da miedo cambiar de carrera. Solo gané la confianza de que podía programar trabajando en los cientos de horas de lecciones gratuitas en freeCodeCamp. En un año tenía un trabajo de seis cifras como ingeniero de software. freeCodeCamp cambio mi vida'        
    },
    {
      nombre:'Sara Chima',
      pais:'Nigeria',
      imagen:'Sarah',
      cargo:'Ingeniero de software',
      empresa:'ChatDesk',
      testimonio:'freeCodeCamp fue la puerta de entrada a mi carrera como desarrollador de software. El plan de estudios bien estructurado llevó mi conocimiento de codificación de un nivel de principiante total a un nivel muy seguro. Era todo lo que necesitaba para conseguir mi primer trabajo de desarrollador en una empresa increíble' 
    },
    {
      nombre:'Emma Bostian',
      pais:'Suecia',
      imagen:'Emma',
      cargo:'Ingeniero de software',
      empresa:'Spotify',
      testimonio:'Siempre me ha costado aprender JavaScript. Tomé muchos cursos, pero el curso de freeCodeCamp fue el que se quedó. Estudiar JavaScript, así como estructuras de datos y algoritmos en freeCodeCamp me dio las habilidades y la confianza que necesitaba para conseguir el trabajo de mis sueños como un ingeniero de software en Spotify'
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='contenedor-principal'>
        <h1>Esto es lo que dicen nuestros alumnos sobre freeCodeCamp:</h1> 

        {
         users.map((user, index)=> { 

         return (<Testimonio
                    key={index}
                    nombre={user.nombre}
                    pais={user.pais}
                    imagen={user.imagen}
                    cargo={user.cargo}
                    empresa={user.empresa}
                    testimonio={user.testimonio}    
                  />)
              })
        }
             
      </div>
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Have you used the css debugger tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `users` array is always going to be declared statically as in your example, you can just define the `testimonio` prop as a [React Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html):

```
const users = [
  {
    nombre: "Shawn Wang",
    pais: "Singapur",
    imagen: "Shawn",
    cargo: "Ingeniero de software",
    empresa: "Amazon",
    testimonio: (
      <span>
        Da miedo cambiar de carrera. Solo gané la confianza de que podía
        programar trabajando en los cientos de horas de lecciones gratuitas en
        freeCodeCamp. En un año tenía un trabajo de seis cifras como ingeniero
        de software. <strong>freeCodeCamp cambio mi vida</strong>
      </span>
    )
  },
  {
    nombre: "Sara Chima",
    pais: "Nigeria",
    imagen: "Sarah",
    cargo: "Ingeniero de software",
    empresa: "ChatDesk",
    testimonio: (
      <>
        <span className="testimonio-highlight">
          freeCodeCamp fue la puerta de entrada a mi carrera
        </span>{" "}
        como desarrollador de software. El plan de estudios bien estructurado
        llevó mi conocimiento de codificación de un nivel de principiante total
        a un nivel muy seguro. Era todo lo que necesitaba para conseguir mi
        primer trabajo de desarrollador en una empresa increíble
      </>
    )
  },
...
```

I've shown a couple of ways you might want to do it - I'd prefer the second personally, using a [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (via its short syntax) and then a specific class (`testimonio-highlight`) for the highlighted part of the `testimonio` so you can easily change it (e.g. italic instead of boldface) in the future.